# Node is always inserted in first node of GLib Tree

Tags: c, tree

I have these structs

```
struct faturacao{
  GTree* meses[12];
};


struct info{
  float valores[6];
  int vendas[3];
  int quantidade[3];
};
```

Initializing:

```
Faturacao initFaturacao(){
  Faturacao fat = malloc(sizeof(struct faturacao));

  for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
    fat -> meses[i] = g_tree_new(cmpStrings);
  }

  return fat;
}
```

Inserting:

```
void insereFaturacao(Faturacao f, Venda v){
  gpointer ptr = g_tree_lookup(f -> meses[(v -> mes) - 1], (v -> produto));

  Info temp;
  if(ptr == NULL){
    temp = calloc(1, sizeof(struct info));
  }
  else{
    temp = (Info)ptr;
  }

  atualizaInfo(temp, v);

  g_tree_insert(f -> meses[(v -> mes)-1], (v -> produto), temp);

  printf("%d\n", g_tree_nnodes(f -> meses[0]));

}
```

AtualizaINfo:

```
void atualizaInfo(Info i, Venda v){
  int index = (v -> promocao == 'N') ? 2 + v -> filial : v -> filial - 1;
  i -> valores[index] += v -> preco * v -> quantidade;
  i -> vendas[(v -> filial)- 1]++;
  i -> quantidade[(v -> filial) - 1] += v -> quantidade;
}
```

Both Venda and Info are pointers so structs, produto is char* in the struct.

Here's cmpStrings

```
int cmpStrings (const void *a, const void *b){
  char* c1 = (char*) a;
  char* c2 = (char*) b;
  return strcmp(c1, c2);
}
```

Im not entirely sure what's happening, but apparently its always replacing the first node, instead of adding another one. I'm kinda lost

Comment: I strongly entourage you to **never** hide a pointer through a _typedef_ this is the source of a lot of problems and that makes your code not readable / confusing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GLib tree insertion always inserts in the same node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55424486/glib-tree-insertion-always-inserts-in-the-same-node)

Comment: please post a [mcve] that include the definition of the struct `Gtree`

Comment: where is `Faturacao` defined?  Please include all relevant information in your question

Comment: OT:  regarding: `Faturacao fat = malloc(sizeof(struct faturacao));`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call `perror( "malloc failed" );` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`